# Why does cut() turn my POSIXct vector into a factor vector and what can I do to stop this?

Tags: r, data.table

How can I use cut while maintaining the POSIXct class of my date.time vector?

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
```

Some data:

```
air.temp <- c(-1.7202,-1.6524,-1.5689,-1.6785,-1.6060,-1.8843)
soil.temp <- c(3.6972,3.6839,3.6716,3.6586,3.6460,3.6701)       
date.time <- c('2007-01-01 00:05:00','2007-01-01 00:10:00',
               '2007-01-01 00:15:00','2007-01-01 00:20:00',
               '2007-01-01 00:25:00','2007-01-01 00:30:00')


DT <- data.table(date.time, air.temp, soil.temp)
DT[, date.time := parse_date_time(date.time, 'YmdHMS')]
```

Structure shows the date.time column is in the desired POSIXTct format:

```
str(DT)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date.time: POSIXct, format: "2007-01-01 00:05:00" ...
 $ air.temp : num  -1.72 -1.65 -1.57 -1.68 -1.61 ...
 $ soil.temp: num  3.7 3.68 3.67 3.66 3.65 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Now I cut five minute data to fifteen minute:

```
DT_15_min <- DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=(date.time = cut(date.time, "15 min"))]
```

Structure shows the conversion to factor vector:

```
str(DT_15_min)

    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date.time: Factor w/ 2 levels "2007-01-01 00:05:00",..: 1 2
 $ air.temp : num  -1.65 -1.72
 $ soil.temp: num  3.68 3.66
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Is it possible to cut while maintaining POSIXct vector class?

My desired result is to have my data agregated from a five minute interval to a fifteen minute interval while maintaining the original class of the vector (POSIXct in this case).

As always, I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: `cut()` always creates factors unless you have `labels=FALSE` which will return indexes. That's described on the `?cut` help page. It's unclear to me exactly what your desired result is. Are you just trying to round values to the nearest 15 min interval?

Comment: From [`cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html): *"labels: labels for the levels of the resulting category.  By default, labels are constructed using '"(a,b]"' interval notation.  If 'labels = FALSE', simple integer codes are returned instead of a factor"*. (Dang, MrFlick, beat me by seconds ...). You can always use `as.character` if you prefer that instead of integers or factors.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I will go back through the help page. I added an edit to clarify desired result. My hope is that a I can use the nice functionality of cut to aggregate without going from POSIXct to a factor and then needing to convert back.

Comment: @r2evans Ok. Thanks guys. Sounds good. I'll tinker with those settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` is designed to return factors. If you want to group by 15 min intervals, you could try using the rounding functions from `lubridate`, e.g.

```
DT_15_min <- DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=(date.time = floor_date(date.time, "15 mins"))]

str(DT_15_min)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date.time: POSIXct, format: "2007-01-01 00:00:00" "2007-01-01 00:15:00" ...
 $ air.temp : num  -1.69 -1.62 -1.88
 $ soil.temp: num  3.69 3.66 3.67
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Beautiful! I was a little off the mark in my understanding of cut. I owe you one... if you're ever in Texas I'm happy to buy you a coffee :)

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use dplyr:

```
df=tibble(date.time, air.temp, soil.temp)%>%mutate(date.time=ceiling_date(ymd_hms(date.time),unit="15 mins"))%>%
  group_by(date.time)%>%summarize_all(funs(mean))
```